# Formar Data URI con Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, base64, data, uri

Estoy intentando formar un Data URI con Python para luego poder procesar la imagen.

El script que tengo es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests, json, base64
from builtins import chr


url = "https://apicovid19.kairosmining.com/auth/new_Captcha"

def main():
        s = requests.session()
        response = s.post(url)
        cadena = response.text
        diccionario = json.loads(cadena)
        lista = diccionario["message"]["data"]
        string = ''.join(map(chr, lista))
        encodedBytes = base64.b64encode(string.encode("utf-8"))
        encodedStr = str(encodedBytes, "utf-8")
        print("data:image/png;base64,"+encodedStr)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Si bien me genera la Data URI, esta no me entrega el captcha con sus valores.

Data URI generada:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Captcha sin valores generado:

[image: resultado_img_captcha]

El resultado que busco es algo como lo siguiente:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no puedes decodificar un string, pues este ya está en UTF-8

Comment: también te puedes ahorrar el `json.loads()` si en vez de recibir la respuesta como texto lo haces como json con `response.json`